# Questions about making props for table top and/or LARP?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering where questions about props and other items for roleplaying games belong.

Things like:

- Making/choosing armour for Larp Characters
- Buying/making/painting Miniatures for a game of DnD
- Where to find good battle matts
- Where to find the best elf ears (for larp)

And so on and so forth. Some of those stradle diy.stack, others would probably fit in others *stacks* that I can't find (wargaming? theatre?). Do they belong in rpg.stack, elsewhere or both?

Answer (score 2):

From our [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

#### What kind of questions can I ask here?

(Questions about)

- Tools and equipment used while playing table-top RPGs

LARPS aren't table-top RPGs, so any questions about them would be off-topic.  However painting for D&D should be OK.

Shopping questions are generally frowned upon on StackExchange sites.  They are likely to be closed as "too localized" as the answers change frequently and most likely vary depending where in the world someone is.

A better StackExchange flavored question would be, "How can I best identify good battle mats?"  Answers that that question may contain specific product recommendations, but a great answer would also have notes:

- how big a mat to look for
- Whether to get a grid on the mat
- The pros and cons of wet-erase vs. dry-erase
- etc

That sort of advice is likely to be useful farther into the future rather than someone just telling you to buy the chessex gray 30" wet erase mat.

#### Other StackExchanges and Migration

Some of this may be on point at DIY as well.  There is no rule that a question can only be valid on just one StackExchange site.  A question will be moved only if it is clearly better  on one site than another.  I encourage you to ask your question on the site that you think could best answer your question.  If there is a consensus that it belongs somewhere else, well, we'll all learn something :)

*Please don't ask the same question on multiple sites at the same time though, that is frowned upon.*

Comment: So questions about making LARP props don't belong in this SO? That was my main question but I realised the idea of props extended outside of LARP.

Comment: Hey, actually, LARP is on topic here by previous community discussion http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165/are-we-including-larps

Comment: @mxyzplk - my bad, lets get the FAQ clear on that

Comment: Other than that, some amount of prop-making (for LARP or for tabletop) is on topic here but if it gets too much into arts-and-crafts this isn't the place for it (just like print layout isn't on topic even though many RPGs are printed books...)

Comment: So I'm *go* on making a larp-prop question?

Comment: @Pureferret - go for it.  The best course is usually to ask the question and see what happens.  Talking on meta is cool and all, but the best way to stretch the boundaries is to ask on the main site.  A lot more of the community will see it there.

Comment: Meta is cool :D

Comment: @Pureferret - true, but agreements reached on meta aren't always binding on the main site.

Comment: fixed the faq...